# UITableView section header iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have multiples tables delegated to a UIViewController. In IOS4 I used the function: `(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` to change the background of some table header section. In those that do not have sections, I return nil and all works fine.

In IOS5 if I return nil, the system puts one default header section. How do I hide the header section in the tables that I have only one section?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Per the release notes, your `UITableViewDelegate` *MUST* now return 0.0 from `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Seems like a real pain. I don't know why they changed this, as everyone relies on the prior behavior - but they must have their reasons.

Comment: No problem. If you could mark my answer as "Accepted" when you get the change I'd be most appreciative!

Comment: What if there is a header? Does returning a height of zero override the height of the header?

Comment: Ryan, in that case you should probably measure your header like you do with table cells and return that value.

Comment: I think the header may be for aesthetic purposes. For example, I have a tabbed app, and one of the tabs didn't have section headers defined. When I switched to that tab, it always looked a bit off. So I will keep the empty header there for aesthetic purposes. I don't think it will be confusing to users.

Comment: I think the documentation is confusing in that it doesn't really explain how the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` work together. I think ios5 is saying that not implementing `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and implementing it and returning nil both have the same meaning semantically - there is no custom view, so use the default one and turn if off if you want by setting the height to 0.